# 2D interpolation after numerical integration

Tags: numerical-integration, interpolation

I have a function which is a result of `NIntegrate` and is a function of two variables. Is it possible to interpolate this function by using the above result form the integration.
The code is the following:

```
result[T1_, T2_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[(T1^5*T2^4) x^3*y*z*ct, {x, 0, 10000}, {y, 0,10000}, {z, 0, 10000}, {ct, -1, 1}, MaxPoints -> 100000,   PrecisionGoal -> 20]
```

Comment: Calculate a table of values: {x,y,result[x,y]} and then use Interpolation

Comment: Presumably, `T1` is not a function of any of the variables of integration. Then the integral can be done exactly, i.e., `Integrate[(T1^5*T2^4) x^3*y*z*ct, {x, 0, 10000}, {y, 0, 10000}, {z, 0, 10000}, {ct, -1, 1}]` evaluates to `0`